# The variable is not defined - Applescript

Tags: variables, applescript

I made was making this applescript to launch apps with a note:

```
tell application "Notes"
if exists note starts with applaunch then
    set LCommands to {"Launch", "Open"}
    repeat with y from 1 to count LCommands
        set applaunch to (item y of LCommands)
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to applaunch
        set myApp to text items 2 thru 1 of note
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}
        set myApp to myApp as text
        if y = 1 or y = 2 then
            tell application myApp to launch
        end if
    end repeat
    delete note starts with applaunch
end tell
```

and returns the error "the variable applaunch is not defined" but i defined it. what to do?

Answer (score 0):

You reference `applaunch` in line 2, but you don't define it until line 5.

Also, your code example is missing the `end if` that goes with `if exists note starts with applaunch then`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something along these lines:

```
set LCommands to {"Launch ", "Open "}

tell application "Notes"
    repeat with aCommand in LCommands
        set aCommand to (contents of aCommand)
        set myNotes to (notes whose name begins with aCommand)
        repeat with aNote in myNotes
            set aNote to contents of aNote
            set noteName to aNote's name
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to aCommand
            set myApp to text items 2 thru -1 of noteName
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}
            set myApp to myApp as text

            -- If you need to work with the Note's content as plain text
            --set noteBody to do shell script "echo " & (quoted form of (aNote's body as text)) & " | textutil -stdin -convert txt -stdout "
            my launchDelete(aNote, myApp)
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell

on launchDelete(theNote, theApp)
    try
        tell application theApp to launch
        tell application "Notes" to delete theNote
    end try
end launchDelete
```